# How does Google ARcore find which phone you are using?

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore

So I have been trying to figure this out for the past week and I am lost, mainly for my own personal hacking.

I understand ARCore needs to be configured per hardware it is running on. Its important that ARcore knows the camera hardware, and its position and orientation with respect to the gyros and accelerometers.

There is probably some config that does this, but I have not found it yet. Does anybody have a clue.

I am an Android dev btw, so keep it Android specific in technology.

Comment: So you've seen: https://github.com/tomthecarrot/arcore-for-all and https://github.com/thestr4ng3r/arcore-patch

Comment: Holy shit that is really helpful

Comment: @noobishProgrammer you wanna know if the phone support ARCore? Or just need to know infos about the phone?